# compressing csv file exported from php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, zip, compression

So I've just started PHP and now I'm coding a script that would take a mysql query and export it into a csv file and then compress it before downloading it. Here is my code

```
    <?php
$filename = "CSVexport";
// Connect to DB..
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';         //database username
$password = '';         // database password
$database = 'script'; // database name
//Connect to MySQL using PDO.
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, FALSE);
//tblclients is the table we are acting on
$resultset = $pdo->query('
    SELECT * FROM tblclients  
    ORDER BY id ASC
');
// Flushing less often requires more server memory usage to maintain the buffer
// but is probably faster and does better gzip compression
$flushEveryXRows = 5000;
// Enable GZIP on-the-fly compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', 9);
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
//creating my zip file
$zipfile = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipfile, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$outputBuffer = fopen("php://temp/maxmemory:$php_memory", 'w');
if($outputBuffer === false) {
    die('Failed to create file');
}
// Create header row of CSV
fputcsv($outputBuffer, [
    'ID', 'uuid', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Company Name', 'Email', 'Address', 'address2', 'City', 'State', 'postcode', 'Country', 'Phone Number', 'taxid', 'password', 'authmodule', 'authdata', 'currency', 'defaultgateway', 'credit', 'taxexempt', 'latefeeoveride', 'overideduenotices', 'separateinvoices', 'disableautocc', 'Date created', 'notes', 'billingcid', 'securityqid', 'securityqans', 'groupid', 'cardtype', 'cardlastfour', 'cardnum', 'Start Date', 'Expiry Date', 'issuenumber', 'bankname', 'banktype', 'bankcode', 'bankacct', 'gatewayid', 'lastlogin', 'ip', 'host', 'Status', 'language', 'pwresetkey', 'emailoptout', 'marketingemailsoptin', 'overrideautoclose', 'allow_sso', 'email_verified', 'created at', 'updated at', 'pwresetexpiry'
]);
// Dump all rows
$count = 56;
while ($r = $resultset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($outputBuffer, $r);
 $zip->addFromString($filename . ".csv", stream_get_contents($outputBuffer));
}
fclose($outputBuffer);
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.zip"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfile));
readfile($zipfile);
unlink($zipfile);
```

So the code above does manage to create a zipped file with a csv inside, but the csv ends up empty, no content from the database is written to the csv. Can anyone please give me a suggestion on what to do. and how also I would add encryption to the zipped file. but as of now, all I need is for the csv in the zipped file to include the content from my database which it's not writing.